# Find minimum or lower bound of $f(x)=\int_{B(0,R)}\log(\frac{|x-y|}{|x-\frac{R^2}{||y||^2}y|})dy$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimization

$$
\mbox{If}\quad\mathrm{f}\left(x\right) =
\int_{B\left(0,R\right)}
\log\left(\frac{\left\vert\,x - y\,\right\vert}
{\left\vert\,x - {R^{\large 2} \over \left\vert\left\vert\,y\,\right\vert\right\vert^{\large 2}}
\,y\,\right\vert}\right)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
where $x\in B\left(0,R\right)$, how to find the minimum or bound of $\mathrm{f}\left(x\right)$ on $x \in B\left(0,R\right)$ only dependent on the radius $R$ ?.

UPDATE:
Taking derivative will only lead to upper bound but not lower bound.
Could anyone kindly help? Thanks.

Comment: Consider what the power of a point theorem tells you about $$\oint_{\Gamma}\log|x-y|\,dy $$ where $\Gamma$ is a circle enclosing $x$. Additionally, it is pretty clear that $f(x)$ only depends on $\|x\|$ and there are not many candidate stationary points in $B(0,R)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you for your hint. I don't quite understand your idea. Can you give me more details?

Answer (score 1):

We have the following Lemma, which is related to the properties of the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel):
$$ \text{if }a\in(0,1),\qquad \int_{0}^{2\pi}\log\left|a-e^{it}\right|\,dt = 0,$$
$$ \text{if }a>1,\qquad \int_{0}^{2\pi}\log\left|a-e^{it}\right|\,dt = 2\pi\log a.$$
Let us focus on $\iint_{B(0,R)}\log|x-y|\,d\mu$.
 By symmetry we may clearly assume that $x\in(0,R)$. With such assumption we have
$$ \iint_{B(0,R)}\log|x-y|\,d\mu = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}\rho \log|x-\rho e^{i\theta}|\,d\rho\,d\theta\\=\int_{0}^{R}2\pi\rho\log\rho+2\pi\rho\max\left(0,\log\frac{x}{\rho}\right)d\rho $$
hence the LHS equals 
$$ \frac{\pi R^2}{2}(2\log R-1)+2\pi\int_{0}^{x}\rho\log\frac{x}{\rho}\,d\rho=\frac{\pi R^2}{2}(2\log R-1)+\frac{\pi x^2}{2}. $$
Similarly,
$$ \iint_{B(0,R)}\log\left|x-\frac{R^2 y}{\|y\|^2}\right|\,d\mu=\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\rho \log\left|x-\frac{R^2}{\rho} e^{i\theta}\right|\,d\theta\,d\rho =\frac{\pi R^2}{2}(2\log R+1)$$
does not really depend on $x$. It follows that for any $R>0$ the minimum of the given integral, $f(x)=-\pi R^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\|x\|^2$, is attained at the origin, and it equals
$$ \iint_{B(0,R)}\log\frac{\|y\|^2}{R^2}\,d\mu = -\pi R^2. $$